# Why does $\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \neq \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x-h) - f(x)}{h} $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, derivatives

I realize that the only reason one-sided limits arise is as a result of the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a limit, applied to the real field $\mathbb{R}$, and that *one-sided* limits aren't even well defined when you move to complex valued functions, but this is a simple question that I can't seem to answer :

Why is the following true (note the $0^{-}$ in the term on the left) :
$$\lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} \neq \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x-h) - f(x)}{h} $$

Since $h \to 0$, for values of $h < 0$ (in this example), why does the the term $f(x+h)$, not become $f(x-h)$.

A simple example is given by $f(x) = |x|$
 $$|x| = \begin{cases}x & \text{if} & x\geq0 \\  -x & \text{if} & x<0 \end{cases}$$

$$f'_{-}(0) = \lim_{h \to 0^-} \frac{f(0-h) - f(x)}{h} = 1$$

Which is wrong, as the correct answer should be $-1$, so why is that we can't change the terms $f(x+h)$ to $f(x-h)$ as $h \to 0^{-}$ ?

Comment: Because for $h < 0$ you have $$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{f(x - \lvert h\rvert) - f(x)}{- \lvert h\rvert}.$$

Comment: "*one-sided limits aren't even well defined when you move to complex valued functions*" -- See [radial limits](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22radial+limits%22+complex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are dealing with an expression like $\lim_{h \to 0}F(h)$ then you are dealing with values of $F(h)$ near $0$ (but not dealing with $F(0)$) and this means value of $F(h)$ for positive as well as negative $h$. When you deal with $\lim_{h \to 0^{-}}F(h)$ you are dealing with values of $F(h)$ near $0$ and $h$ is always negative.

In the expression $$\lim_{h \to 0^{-}}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}\tag{1}$$ you are essentially dealing with values of $f$ at $x$ (i.e. $f(x)$) and **values of $f$ at points which are near to but less that $x$ (i.e $f(x + h)$ and $x + h < x$). At the same time the denominator is negative**.

Now check the expression $$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x - h) - f(x)}{h}\tag{2}$$ Here we are dealing with values of $f$ at $x$ as well as values of $f$ near $x$ and this time since $h$ can be positive as well as negative, we are dealing with values of $f$ at points less than $x$ as well as at points greater than $x$. Also if we are dealing with **values of $f$ at points less than $x$ (so that $h$ is positive) then the denominator is positive** and if we are dealing with **values of $f$ at points greater than $x$ then denominator is negative**.

You can clearly see that the bold statement in last to last paragraph does not match any of the two bold statements in last paragraph. And hence *these expressions $(1)$ and $(2)$ are completely different things. They may be same by luck and not by any rule of logical inference.*

The logically correct statement is $$\lim_{h \to 0^{-}}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^{+}}\frac{f(x - h) - f(x)}{-h}$$ and you can check that they are referring to the same thing by using the kind of **bold statements** as I used in my earlier paragraphs. Or to be more technical/formal the expression on LHS gets transformed into that on RHS via the substitutions $h = -t$ and $h = t$ applied one after another in succession.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent answer!

Answer (score 2):

You’ve calculated the last limit incorrectly:

$$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(0-h)-f(0)}h=-1\;,$$

not $1$. When $h$ is just a little less than $0$, $f(0-h)=f(-h)=|-h|=-h$, since $-h>0$, so the fraction is $\frac{-h}h=-1$.

However, it’s still not quite true that

$$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}h\;:$$

it’s possible for the first limit to exist when the second does not. The correct statement is that

$$\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim_{h\to 0^{\color{red}{+}}}\frac{f(x-h)-f(x)}{-h}\;,$$

so that both limits are one-sided.

Comment: Shouldn't there be $-h$ in the denominator  (in RHS) in your last equation? Perhaps a typo which you missed.

Comment: @Paramanand: It was indeed; thanks for catching it.